# align the decimal point when displaying doubles without adding extra trailing zeros

Tags: java

I would like to convert Double to String and align the decimal point.

Let's say that I have these doubles:

```
251          
0.00640035   
-40.16219625 
0.03359965   
-210.83780375
-0.04        
283.96
```

I can display them easily with `String.format("%10.8f", amount)` but it adds trailling zesos:

```
 251.00000000
   0.00640000
 -40.16219000
   0.03359000
-210.83780000
  -0.04000000
 283.96000000
```

I do not need these zeros. I would like to have this result:

```
 251          
   0.00640035   
 -40.16219625 
   0.03359965   
-210.83780375
  -0.04        
 283.96
```

The `new DecimalFormat("#####.########").format(amount)` is also not good, it does different thing.

There are multiply solutions on Stackowerflow but all of them do string manipulation in a small function. I do not want to add an extra method for this.

Is there any super-easy Java built-in way to do this?

Comment: Why do you not want to add an extra method? If it's clean code, what do you gain by not using it?

Comment: How about `"%13.8f".formatted(amount).replaceFirst("\\.?0*$", "")`.

Comment: This works like a charm and is so elegant. If u post it as a solution I will accept it. Thx